# Better Practice: Delete&Insert vs. Update

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, database-administration

I need to parse data (~60000 rows) from CSV file and write them to MSSQL table (the data is Date/Time and Value which is a decimal number).
Each day I get one such CSV file.
The catch is, that in the CSV file that I get each day I have data from the last 5 days, meaning that I have data for dates which I already wrote in the past days, but I need to replace it with the data from the file.

I am trying to decide between two methods:
Bulk DELETE of old data that I need to re-write when I get new CSV file, and INSERT, vs finding each record based on date&time and ID and UPDATE it.

1.What is a better practice that will cause less fragmentation and maintenance issues on my database?

2. Which will be be less expensive from Performance point of view?

If it comes to choosing between the two, I prefer keeping my DB in good shape over high performance because the file will be written during the night anyway.

EDIT: In case that I'll add a maintenance plan that rebuilds the indexes on daily basis after I do bulk deletion and insertion of new data, will this be enough to avoid fragmentation issues, or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Have you considered `MERGE'?

Comment: Is the previous 4 days of data always the same that you already have? So that you actually wouldn't even update anything?

Comment: @Dan, thanks, I never heard of 'MERGE. I looked into it now and it seems like it can do the trick. Do you know the implications of such daily 'MERGE on the fragmantation state of the Database?

Comment: @JamesZ, the 4 days will not be the same, there can be changes, otherwise obviously I wouldn't need to re-write the data.

Comment: @LimS, I added an answer with a `MERGE` example and fragmentation explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Faster & better way is to delete all old data, import data with SSIS or bulk insert in a case if you don't have SSIS and then rebuild fragmented indexes. As an example by [script](http://sqlfool.com/2011/06/index-defrag-script-v4-1/).

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSIS, but I saw that it is not supported in SQL WEB EDITION 2008 R2, so it is not relevant for me

Comment: You can use bulk insert instead of SSIS, but it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with insert all the data in you CSV file and them remove duplicate data.

The code below helps you to delete duplicates. 
I hope it helps you :)

```
delete b from    your_table c join
(SELECT max(a.id) id, a.date
 FROM your_table a 

GROUP BY a.date 
having count(0) > 1
) as b
on c.date = b.date
and c.id <> b.id
```

Comment: Thanks @Liz, but what can you tell me regarding performance and fragmentation?

Comment: If have test this with millions of records. And with the proper indices it takes couples of seconds. About Fragmentation  can give you any opinions. I am not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MERGE technique using a staging table with the parsed CSV data.  Alternatively, you could use a table valued parameter instead of a staging table source.

Regarding your fragmentation concern, it will mostly depend on how many new rows are inserted within the existing target table date range.  Without new rows in that range, fragmentation is insignificant (under 3% as the script below shows.  You can always perform an index `REBUILD` or `REORGANIZE` after the ETL if fragmentation becomes problematic.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
      TestDateTime datetime2(0) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY
    , TestData int NOT NULL
    );
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestStaging(
      TestDateTime datetime2(0) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_TestStaging PRIMARY KEY
    , TestData int NOT NULL
    );
GO

--load 10 days into main table (61710 per day)
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t256K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) - 1 AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test WITH(TABLOCKX) (TestDateTime, TestData) 
SELECT DATEADD(second, num*7, CAST('2015-07-01T00:00:00' AS datetime2(0))), num
FROM t256K
WHERE num <= 123420;
GO

--load 4 most recent days with new values plus 1 new day into staging table
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t256K AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) - 1 AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestStaging WITH(TABLOCKX) (TestDateTime, TestData) 
SELECT DATEADD(second, num*7, CAST('2015-07-07T00:00:06' AS datetime2(0))), num
FROM t256K
WHERE num <= 61710;
GO

--show fragmentation before MERGE
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Test'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED');
GO

MERGE dbo.Test AS target
USING dbo.TestStaging AS source ON
    source.TestDateTime = target.TestDateTime
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TestData = source.TestData
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (TestDateTime, TestData) VALUES (source.TestDateTime, source.TestData);
GO

--show fragmentation after MERGE
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Test'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED');
GO
```